# What was the Fairy Godmother and King Harold's deal?

Tags: shrek

In the movie *Shrek 2*, when King Harold and the Fairy Godmother are in her "car" she says

> "we had a deal, and I assume you don't want me to go back on my part".

**What was the deal?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*unmarked spoilers to follow*

Canonically it isn't stated.

However one can assume that since the King was actually a frog originally and he fell in love with a human princess the deal was to turn Harold into a human prince so he could marry said princess.

Comment: Why the downvote? The deal is easily inferred, as RicoRicochet's answer proves, but the terms of the deal are never laid out in detail, just referred to

Answer (score 48):

The deal was - **the Fairy Godmother would help King Harold (i.e. the Frog Prince) to marry Lilian (i.e. Fiona's mom)** via Happily Ever After Potion. And in return, **the King would let the Fairy Godmother's son Prince Charming marry Princess Fiona.**

That was the plan all along. That once Prince Charming grows old enough, he will rescue Fiona and marry her. Quotes as below showing the disappointment of Fairy Godmother -

> **King Harold:** Charming! Is that you? My gosh, it's been years! When did you get back?
>
> **Charming:** (Irritated) Oh, about five minutes ago, actually. [Raised tone] After I endured blistering winds! And scorching desert!
>   Climbed to the highest room of the tallest tower--- (Cut off by the
>   Fairy Godmother)
>
> **Fairy Godmother:** (Concerned for Prince Charming's upset tone) Tut, tut, tut. Mummy can handle this. [to King Harold, using the same
>   hostile tone Charming used earlier] He endures blistering winds and
>   scorching desert! He climbs to the highest bloody room of the tallest
>   bloody tower! and what does he find?! Some gender-confused wolf
>   telling him (Harold tries to explain but gets interrupted) that his
>   princess (Harold attempts to explain again) (The Fairy Godmother's
>   voice is more settled now) is already married!

And then again from the fast food joint scene, the threatening becomes even more clear,

> **Fairy Godmother:** We made a deal, Harold, and I assume you don't want me to go back on my part.
>   **King Harold:** [sighs deeply] Indeed not.
>   **Fairy Godmother:** So, Fiona and Charming will be together.
>   **King Harold:** Yes.
>   **Fairy Godmother:** Believe me, Harold. It's what's best. Not only for your daughter...but for your kingdom.

Courtesy - wikiquotes.org and moviescript