# Was King Harold born a human or a frog?

Tags: shrek

In *Shrek 2*, King Harold intercepts a curse intended for the titular character so that it rebounds and hits the Fairy Godmother. She evaporates and it appears as though (at least some of) her former spells are reversed.

As a result of this King Harold becomes a frog. Does this mean that:

- Harold was born a frog and the Fairy Godmother had previously made him human?
- Jumping in front of the spell somehow turned Harold into a frog?
- Harold was born a human, was turned into a frog, was "cured by The Fairy Godmother", which was then subsequently reversed with her downfall?

In short - what chain of events led to King Harold being turned into a frog?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94924/19592) provides a very good explanation. To summarise:

- King Harold is The Frog Prince, he was born a frog
- The Fairy Godmother gave him the Happily Ever After Potion so he could marry Lilian (Fiona's mother and the current queen)
- In exchange the King would let Fairy Godmother's son (Prince Charming) marry Princess Fiona

He was born a frog and when TFG was defeated her magic was reversed and both Happily Ever After potion instances were discarded (both Shrek's and Harold's).

Comment: I feel a little bad that this answer now has more votes than the one I copied the answer from. If you haven’t already please do vote for that one too!

Comment: Another related answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/94966/2344

Comment: Was the Frog Prince really born a frog? The versions of the story I am familiar with all have him be a human who was turned into a frog by an Evil Witch, whose spell was undone by the kiss of the princess. I saw Shrek many years ago, so I don't remember, is it shown that he was an actual frog in this version?

Comment: @terdon Ha, but do those versions also feature an ogre and an annoying donkey? I mean, are you sure it's the same story?

Comment: @MrLister not at all. That's what I'm asking. I don't remember if it is made clear in Shrek that the Frog Prince was originally a frog and neither this answer nor the cited one give any evidence for their claiming it. I assume it's somehow shown in the movie, but it would be nice to mention that, if so.

Comment: @terdon OK, I confess it's been a while since I saw this movie too, but I'm pretty sure it was clear that Harold had now reverted to his original form. No matter what other stories which Shrek is based on may say.

Comment: @Liath And who was that female frog in the poison apple tavern who told Harold he is so familiar to her?

Comment: _"when TFG was defeated her magic was reversed and both Happily Ever After potion instances were discarded"_ IIRC that's not the case, Harold gets hit by a wayward spell and Shrek's potion's time runs out. The magic never reverts?